# I cant use proguard with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

When I generate signed APK of my application without Proguard, it works fine.

But If I set minifyEnabled to true and generate APK again, I will get this error on running application. I can install APK on my device but whenever I try to run it I get this error.
I check both V1 and V2 options on choosing signature versions.

Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 

I get this error when I use this line in proguard config

Unexpected keyword 'com.google.**' in line 26 of file 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Whoops. I should have said `-keep class com.google.** { *; }`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That didn't work

Comment: Do you by chance get a different error now?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
No that's the same